# Multibib does not work

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I have the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=35mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{Art}{Bibliography: Articles}

\begin{document}

Text \cite{Textbook}, \citeArt{Article}

%References
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{alpha} 
\bibliography{Referenzen}

\newpage
\bibliographystyleArt{alpha} 
\bibliographyArt{Articles}

\end{document}
```

But as an output I got only ''[Textbookblabla], [?]'' and also only the bibliography of ''Referenzen'' and not that one of Articles....
`

Comment: Yeah I tried many times.....I run all my documents with bibtex in all possible orderings.....I also have deleted the various .aux files and have tried again and again.....

Comment: Did you run `bibtex Art`? With `multibib` you may have to run BibTeX on several different files. In your setup you need to run BibTeX on your the base name of your main file `bibtex <filename>` and on Art `bibtex Art`.

Comment: Can you share the `.blg` file of the BibTeX run on the main file and on Art? Can you share the `.log` file of the LaTeX run after the required BibTeX run? (The `.log` file may be too long to be pasted here in full, so you can upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to reference the same .bib file for all of your references.  For instance, you have

```
    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{alpha} 
    \bibliography{Referenzen}

    \newpage
    \bibliographystyleArt{alpha} 
    \bibliographyArt{Articles}
```

where you reference two .bib files (Referenzen and Articles).  Based on what I read in the [multibib manual](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) I think it has to be the same .bib file, either Referenzen.bib or Articles.bib.  Maybe try consolidating into one single .bib file.